# Which type of MOSFET is required to supply enough current to activate the coils?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, relay, schematic

I am using a NPN-PNP Transistor couple to act as a switch for activating the desired coil of my relay. If the H/L pin is in HIGH state, COIL1 must be supplied with 3.3V and if LOW, COIL2 must be supplied with 3.3V.

I am in search of MOSFETs  to place before the coils, which will feed the required amount of current to activate both coils.

My question is, which type of MOSFET should I chose for such an application? Or is there a easier way?

Coil specs: Nominal voltage:3V, Coil Resistance:54.4ohm, Set Voltage:2.25V, Nominal Operating Power: 140 mW

I am a beginner so I would appriciate some help. Regards[image]

Comment: This is not the right circuit arrrangement to use to control a relay coil. In this arrangement all of the relay coil current has to go through a 47k resistor which will prevent enough current from passing to actually activate the coil.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I was told that all I have to do is to add a MOSFET between the resistor and the coils. 

If I change the R3 and R4 resistors with a smaller resistance will it work?

Comment: What type of relay are you using? How is it connected?